# How to make dbms_metadata.get_ddl more pretty/useful

Tags: oracle, ddl, plsqldeveloper, dbms-metadata

I am creating a package to generate the DDL of objects in my schema (you parse the object name, and return a `clob` with DDL), so I can generate files, and put them straight into SVN.

I am using `dbms_metadata.get_ddl`, and it works great for all objects except tables/materialized views.

If I create a table as:

```
create table stackoverflow
     ( col_1 varchar2(64)
     , col_2 number
     , col_3 date);

create index idx_test on stackoverflow(col_1);

alter table stackoverflow add constraint ui_test unique (col_2) using index;
```

And generate DDL with:

```
begin
   dbms_output.put_line(dbms_metadata.get_ddl( object_type => 'TABLE'
                                             , name => 'STACKOVERFLOW')
                        );
end;
```

It gives us:

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST_SCHEMA"."STACKOVERFLOW" 
 (  "COL_1" VARCHAR2(64), 
  "COL_2" NUMBER, 
  "COL_3" DATE, 
   CONSTRAINT "UI_TEST" UNIQUE ("COL_2")
USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
STORAGE(INITIAL 131072 NEXT 131072 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "USERS_DATA_TS"  ENABLE
 ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
STORAGE(INITIAL 131072 NEXT 131072 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "USERS_DATA_TS"
```

To take all relevant indexes we can use:

```
begin
   dbms_output.put_line(dbms_metadata.get_dependent_ddl( object_type => 'INDEX'
                                                       , base_object_name => 'STACKOVERFLOW'));
end;
```

to have:

```
CREATE INDEX "TEST_SCHEMA"."IDX_TEST" ON "MF"."STACKOVERFLOW" ("COL_1") 
PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
STORAGE(INITIAL 131072 NEXT 131072 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "USERS_DATA_TS" 
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "TEST_SCHEMA"."UI_TEST" ON "MF"."STACKOVERFLOW" ("COL_2") 
PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
STORAGE(INITIAL 131072 NEXT 131072 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "USERS_DATA_TS"
```

I want to create a file that contains: create table, constraints, indexes, grants (to have one file with all definition needed) and using `dbms_metadata` it looks impossible for me to do.

My problems with the output is:

1. Double quotation of the name
2. Schema name inside the DDL make us difficult to compile the same DDL across many schemas. To fix that we need to create some for of regex or adding something like the following can fix that:

   ```
    dbms_metadata.SET_REMAP_PARAM(dbms_metadata.SESSION_TRANSFORM,'REMAP_SCHEMA','TEST_SCHEMA','');
   ```

   but you have to add like 8 more lines:

   ```
   hOpenOrig0 := DBMS_METADATA.OPEN('TABLE');
   DBMS_METADATA.SET_FILTER(hOpenOrig0,'NAME',p_object_name);
   DBMS_METADATA.SET_FILTER(hOpenOrig0,'SCHEMA',get_table.owner);
   tr := dbms_metadata.add_transform(hOpenOrig0, 'MODIFY');
   hTransDDL := DBMS_METADATA.ADD_TRANSFORM(hOpenOrig0,'DDL');
   dbms_metadata.set_remap_param(tr, name => 'REMAP_SCHEMA', old_value => user, new_value => '');
   get_package_spec.ddl := DBMS_METADATA.FETCH_CLOB(hOpenOrig0);
   DBMS_METADATA.CLOSE(hOpenOrig0);
   ```
3. There is no way of extracting constraints (that use indexes) and indexes at the same moment. You can't concatenate the output because of repeating definition of `ui_test`. Yes there is option to remove the constraints from `get_ddl` but we are loosing constraint/checks.
4. How PL/SQL Developer creates the output

   ```
   -- Create table
   create table STACKOVERFLOW
   (
     col_1 VARCHAR2(64),
     col_2 NUMBER,
     col_3 DATE
   )
   tablespace USERS_DATA_TS
     pctfree 10
     pctused 40
     initrans 1
     maxtrans 255
     storage
     (
       initial 128K
       next 128K
       minextents 1
       maxextents unlimited
       pctincrease 0
     );
   -- Create/Recreate indexes 
   create index IDX_TEST on STACKOVERFLOW (COL_1)
     tablespace USERS_DATA_TS
     pctfree 10
     initrans 2
     maxtrans 255
     storage
     (
       initial 128K
       next 128K
       minextents 1
       maxextents unlimited
       pctincrease 0
     );
   -- Create/Recreate primary, unique and foreign key constraints 
   alter table STACKOVERFLOW
     add constraint UI_TEST unique (COL_2)
     using index 
     tablespace USERS_DATA_TS
     pctfree 10
     initrans 2
     maxtrans 255
     storage
     (
       initial 128K
       next 128K
       minextents 1
       maxextents unlimited
       pctincrease 0
     );
   ```

Does anybody know of a way to create output similar to PL/SQL Developer? I guess they created some XML parser of `dbms_metadata.get_xml`) to create a more pretty version (indents, order, all in good place, ready to compile anywhere).

Of course I can play with regexes or `user_indexes` but that's not the point.

ps. `DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM,'PRETTY',true);` is a strange definition what's "pretty".

Comment: you can remove the schema prefixes using dbms_metadata.set_transform_param - there's a flag to not show or to remap schema TEST_SCHEMA to null. PL/SQL Developer doesn't use dbms_metadata to generate the ddl, so no quotes there.

Answer (score 10):

dbms_metadata.get_dll gets oracle object  as xml and next transform it by xslt to ddl script.

List of useful table `select table_name from all_tables where table_name like 'META%'`.

1. METASTYLESHEET - maps a stylesheet to it's name
2. METAXSL$ - maps an XMLTAG to the stylesheet name - link this to the 1st table
3. METAVIEW$ - maps an object type to an XMLTAG - link this to ghe 2nd table
4. METAXSLPARAM$ - lookup table for the transform filters available for each object type and transform type.

For a table oracle uses kutable for xml to ddl for a index oracle uses kuindex ... etc.

By setting parameters you can change behavior of transformation. To find useful parameter check METAXSLPARAM$ table or search  it in style sheet documents.
EMIT_SCHEMA - i have found in kucommon xslt

```
EXECUTE DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM,'EMIT_SCHEMA',false);  --undocumented remove schema
EXECUTE DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM,'SEGMENT_CREATION',false);  --undocumented remove segement creation
EXECUTE DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM,'CONSTRAINTS_AS_ALTER',true);
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl( object_type => 'TABLE' , name => 'STACKOVERFLOW') from dual;
```

Comment: Really helpful. For sure it solve part of my problems (`'EMIT-SCHEMA'`) that I fixed with `regexp`... 
It doesn't completely solve my problems but I will look into all the parameters

Comment: Unfortunately there is nothing really interesting apart of emit-schema... Investigating more I found even more problems with get_dll... I think I will have to raise some ticket straight to Oracle

Comment: Also note that `SEGMENT_CREATION` seems to be no longer available with 12i (threw an error here). Furthermore I miss the `COMMENT ON` with `get_ddl` – plus it irritates that multiple statements (`CREATE TABLE` … `ALTER TABLE`) are generated with `CONSTRAINTS_AS_ALTER`, but not properly separated (not a single semicolon found). Is there another parameter missing, like `dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'SQLTERMINATOR', true);`? ;)

Comment: I don't know. I never touched oracle 12 :D

Comment: Fair enough :) I usually recommend my customers to skip R1 and wait for R2 (more stable), but my current customer had decided ahead of my arrival ;) Still: You might wish to include the `SQLTERMINATOR` setting with your answer, so the reverse-engineered code is executable.

Answer (score -2):

May I suggest you using expdp / impdp for ddl export purposes.

Export Schema: `faydin` with following expdp.

`expdp userid=faydin/***** directory=ORA_TMP_DIR reuse_dumpfiles=y  content=METADATA_ONLY exclude=STATISTICS schemas=faydin dumpfile=metadata.dmp`

Get ddl in `ddl.sql` for  `user : faydin  remapped as: faydin3` with impdp

`impdp userid=faydin/***** directory=ORA_TMP_DIR dumpfile=metadata.dmp sqlfile=ddl.sql remap_schema=faydin:faydin3`

Import schema to db by deleting `sqlfile=ddl.sql` phrase in impdp command.